# Using AddPooledDbContextFactory with AspNetCore.Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, hotchocolate

I've got asp.net core webapi app which currently uses `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity` and `services.AddDbContext` in `ConfigureServices` methods in `Startup` class and everything works so far.

I tried to use `services.AddPooledDbContextFactory` instead of `services.AddDbContext` to improve performance. However when I try to use `AddPooledDbContextFactory` I've got an error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type
> 'hostapp.Data.DataContext' while attempting to activate
> 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.RoleStore`5[hostapp.Models.AppRole,hostapp.Data.DataContext,System.Int32,hostapp.Models.AppUserRole,Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRoleClaim`1[System.Int32]]'

After seeing this error I created new webapi project which uses `AddPooledDbContextFactory` without `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity` which works fine. So my question is:

**What is the proper way of using `services.AddPooledDbContextFactory` with `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity` to avoid error above?**

in `ProjectRoot/Startup.cs`

```cs
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using hostapp.Data;
using hostapp.GraphQL;
using hostapp.Interfaces;
using hostapp.Models;
using hostapp.Services;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

namespace hostapp
{
    public class Startup
    {
        
        // ...
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddScoped<ICookieService, CookieService>();
            
            // EARLIER IMPLEMENTATION WHICH WORKS FINE =>
            // services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(options =>
            // {
            //     options.UseSqlServer(_config.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
            // });

            // CURRENT IMPLEMENTATION WHICH CAUSES AN ERROR
            services.AddPooledDbContextFactory<DataContext>(options =>
            {
                options.UseSqlServer(_config.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
            });

            services.AddIdentityCore<AppUser>(opt =>
            {
                opt.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
            })
            .AddRoles<AppRole>()
            .AddRoleManager<RoleManager<AppRole>>()
            .AddSignInManager<SignInManager<AppUser>>()
            .AddRoleValidator<RoleValidator<AppRole>>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<DataContext>();

            services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddCookie(options =>
            {
                options.Cookie.Name = "app-cookie";
                // options.Cookie.Expiration = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
                options.Events.OnRedirectToLogin = context =>
                {
                    context.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized;
                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                };
            });

            services.AddAuthorization(opt =>
            {
                opt.AddPolicy("RequireAdminRole", policy => policy.RequireRole("Admin"));
            });

            services
                .AddGraphQLServer()
                .AddAuthorization()
                .AddQueryType<Query>();

            services.AddControllers();
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseCors(options => options
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .WithOrigins("https://localhost:4200")
                .SetIsOriginAllowed(origin => true)
                .AllowCredentials());

            app.UseCookiePolicy(new CookiePolicyOptions
            {
                MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.Strict,
                // HttpOnly = Microsoft.AspNetCore.CookiePolicy.HttpOnlyPolicy.Always,
                // Secure = CookieSecurePolicy.Always
            });

            app.UseAuthentication();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
                endpoints.MapGraphQL();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

in `ProjectRoot/Data/DataContext.cs`

```cs
using hostapp.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace hostapp.Data
{
    public class DataContext : IdentityDbContext<AppUser, AppRole, int,
                               IdentityUserClaim<int>, AppUserRole, IdentityUserLogin<int>,
                               IdentityRoleClaim<int>, IdentityUserToken<int>>
    {
        public DataContext(DbContextOptions<DataContext> options) : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<AppUserClaim> Claims { get; set; }
        public DbSet<AppUserClaimOffender> Offenders { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);

            builder.Entity<AppUser>()
                .HasMany(ur => ur.AppUserRoles)
                .WithOne(u => u.AppUser)
                .HasForeignKey(ur => ur.UserId)
                .IsRequired();

            builder.Entity<AppRole>()
                .HasMany(ur => ur.AppUserRoles)
                .WithOne(u => u.AppRole)
                .HasForeignKey(ur => ur.RoleId)
                .IsRequired();
        }
    }
}
```

in `ProjectRoot/app.csproj`

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies" Version="2.2.0"/>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" Version="5.0.0" NoWarn="NU1605"/>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect" Version="5.0.0" NoWarn="NU1605"/>
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="5.6.3"/>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="5.0.0"/>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="5.0.0"/>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="5.0.0"/>
    <PackageReference Include="HotChocolate.AspNetCore" Version="11.1.0"/>
    <PackageReference Include="HotChocolate.AspNetCore.Authorization" Version="11.1.0"/>
    <PackageReference Include="HotChocolate.Data.EntityFramework" Version="11.1.0"/>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors" Version="2.2.0"/>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What is the proper way of using services.AddPooledDbContextFactory
> with Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity to avoid error above?

In the ConfigureServices, try to use AddScoped() method to register the DBContext and use the provider to get the factory from the services. Then, return the instance to the provider. The code like this:

```
        services.AddPooledDbContextFactory<DataContext>(options =>
        {
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
            options.EnableSensitiveDataLogging();
        }, poolSize:32);

        services.AddScoped<DataContext>(p => p.GetRequiredService<IDbContextFactory<DataContext>>().CreateDbContext());
```

Comment: when i do this i get ```System.InvalidOperationException: 'Cannot resolve scoped service 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IPersonalDataProtector' from root provider.'```

How can if overcome this?