# Using a AddPooledDbContextFactory with AspNetCore.Identity and Dataprotection

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, hotchocolate

My issue is fairly similar to this question: [Using AddPooledDbContextFactory with AspNetCore.Identity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66955768/using-addpooleddbcontextfactory-with-aspnetcore-identity). But while it helped  my issue is not the same.

I have an API that uses Duende `IdentityServer` and `AspNetCore.Identity`. I use dataprotection to protect my users data in the database. However I also want to use GraphQL to expose a list of my users etc. The Hot Chocolate GraphQL package  required that you use a pooled `dbContext` because it will sometimes execute multiple queries at once and this could cause an error in a normal `dbContext` registration.

When I use `AddPooledDbContextFactory`, however, I can't seem to get the `AspNetCoreIdentity` to run properly in combination with `DataProtection`. (It did work with a normal `AddDbContext<>`)

Here is my code:

```cs
var redis = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(configurationOptions);
services.AddSingleton(redis);
services.AddDataProtection().SetApplicationName("app").PersistKeysToStackExchangeRedis(redis, "DataProtectionKeys");
services.AddScoped<ILookupProtectorKeyRing, KeyRing>();
services.AddScoped<ILookupProtector, LookupProtector>();
services.AddScoped<IPersonalDataProtector, PersonalDataProtector>();

// some other code 
    
services.AddPooledDbContextFactory<IdentityContext>((ctx) => ctx.UseNpgsql(dataOptions.ConnectionString));
services.AddScoped<IdentityContext>(p => p.GetRequiredService<IDbContextFactory<IdentityContext>>().CreateDbContext());
services.AddIdentity<User, IdentityRole>(options => {
    options.Stores.ProtectPersonalData = true;
    options.Stores.MaxLengthForKeys = 128;
})
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<IdentityContext>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

The error I receive is this :

```
Cannot resolve scoped service 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IPersonalDataProtector' from root provider.
```

Can  anyone provide me with some insight how to fix this?

Edit: I figured that I would dive into the DI of DataProtection. [Here](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/ce78832442d91ca307ca8366bafdc9003ea46bc9/src/DataProtection/DataProtection/src/DataProtectionServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L90) you can see that it is registered as a singleton. So I don't understand the issue.